Looking for a free Python IDE for Linux that supports type hints
Looking for a Python IDE with good support of type hints that can:

Check that those that I add make sense
Complain when the code written doesn't use the proper types
Suggest completions when using functions/methods with such hints

I tried PyCharm Community but it seems to totally ignore them.
Currently on Ubuntu 24.04 if that makes a difference.

You won't really find any that does that by default. PyCharm is the most specialistic one by far. It also claims to support some of the features you mentioned, in both Pro and Community versions.
You could maybe give Visual Studio Code + Python extension a go, to check for the 2nd most popular alternative. There's python.analysis.typeCheckingMode setting that works with error reporting for type hints. Then there's also Python Type Hint extension for limited completions.
